# how to add some product are printable and some not in magento?

Tags: magento

What is the use of "this product is printable"?
And some product not display icon of print.
How to implement in magento?
See design of magento layout product list page.

[image]

Comment: Hello Shraddha, Possibly its not the default behavior of magento.Hopefully u need to check some available extension for implementing this functionality.Please let know the version of magento used.

Comment: magento 1.9.0.1.and i found this plugin http://blog.chapagain.com.np/print-product-cart-page-magento-extension-free/ but it is apply to all products

Comment: I am not sure about the module configuration.But if it need to be done through coding.You need to create a product attribute of yes/no type and while creating a product set the product to yes if you want to display the print product and no if you don't want to dispaly the print product hyperlink .

Comment: Thank you for Help.I have solved my Problem in magento stack exchange link: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101740/how-to-add-some-product-are-printable-and-some-not-in-magento

Comment: As i thought the solution seems to be same .good to know the problem is resolved cheers!!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103477/discussion-between-shraddha-gajjar-and-mageotron).